# Updating an Entity in Command with Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.4, symfony-console

I am trying to create a command for console using Symfony 3.4. Basically adding a role via console.

First, I was able to get the doctrine via `ContainerAwareCommand`

```
$em = $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getManager();
```

Then get the user object from the input like so

```
$user = $em->getRepository(User::class)->findByUsername($username);
```

Error shows for this line:

```
$user->setRole($role);
```

Error:

```
Error: Call to a member function setRole()
```

---

Entity:

```
/**
  * @ORM\Column(name="role", type="string", nullable=true)
  */
  private $role;
 .....
  public function setRole($role)
    {
        $this->role = $role;

        return $this;
    }
    ...
```

Comment: can you show your User entity? Is Role a reference of other object? have you the method `setRole()` in User entity?

Comment: added, pretty standard string type and setter.  I have also tried it on other setters and received same issue.

Comment: Can you add the output of `get_class($user)` just before the `$user->setRole()` call aswell? Are you checking if your method returns a `null` value (eg. user not found)?

Comment: OMG! @ccKep, you definitely led me to the right path.  The result says $user is not an object but an array. Yeah, I said what???.  Then I found that I used `findByUsername` instead of `findOneByUsername`.  Put this as answer and ill vote! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In response to your comments:

Debugging by taking a look at `$user` via `get_class()` right before the `->setRole` call led to the conclusion of it being an array.

Looking at your code again, you mistakenly used `findByUsername` (which returns an array of results) instead of `findOneByUsername` (which returns exactly one result or `null`).